# Reading from a file with unexpected output

Tags: java, file-handling

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;


class Myclass
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try{
                //writing data into file from byte stream i.e FileOutputStream and  reading from DataInputStream    
                int data[]={99,76,65,55,99};
                FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\testingfile.txt");

                for(int i:data)
                {
                    fout.write(i);
                }
            Myclass m=new Myclass();
            FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\testingfile.txt");
            m.readMethod(fin);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception caught");
            }
    }

 void readMethod(InputStream obj)
  {
    try{
        DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(obj);//noe datainputstream has only one constructor with parameter of Inputstream
        int d;
        while((d=din.readInt())!=-1)
        {
            System.out.println(d);
        }
    }catch(Exception E){}

  }
```

> > I am writing set of integers to the file testingfile.txt with the write(int) method available in FileOutPutStream.I have created a method readMethod which reads Integer from file with method available in DataInputStream.But reading from an file gives me different output.It differs from data i have written.Why is my Output different?Can anyone correct my code or tell me why is that so?
> >     Output is :1665941815.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> void  write(int b) 
>   Writes the specified byte to this file output stream.

In JavaSE documentation(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html), write method is used to write a **byte**, but not int, even it receive a int value as parameter.

Maybe you need to use DataOutputStream instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot .Does It mean that even though i am writing int Implicitly it is converted to a byte and written in a File?

Comment: yep, it is. So you'd better be care of the document.